# Avoid opening Play Store after NFC scan for unlocking with Smart Lock

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, nfc, smart-lock

I want to use the Smart Lock feature of Android 5.0 Lollipop together with NFC. I've configured it and it works well, but my problem is, that after scanning the NFC Tag (and also after unlocking the phone) the Play Store opens and wants me to download an NFC app.

I only want to use NFC for the Smart Lock feature, so basically I want the phone to do just nothing after an NFC scan. Is this possible?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you mention the particular NFC app that is opened on Play Store?

Comment: Sure, it's the app "Trigger" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher&hl=de)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the answer by Michael Roland on same problem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377309/2821954),

> Play Store opening up after scanning a tag is a clear indication that the tags contain an [*Android Application Record (AAR)*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar). A tag containing an AAR will only start the app referenced in the AAR or will open that app's Play Store page.
>
> In order to re-use the tags, you should first format them or simply overwrite them with some other NDEF message that does not contain an AAR.
>
> You could, for instance, use an app like [NXP TagWriter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter) to do that. [the rest is redacted due to related to app development]